# Nice round edges?? With css?

Tags: css

Can I make nice round edges, such as those shown in this image, using CSS?

[image]

Comment: Do you have some code regarding you tried to achieve?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Or this one ....

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
#box{

  width:200px;

  height: 50px;


  border :2px solid; 

  border-top-right-radius:20px;

  border-style: dashed;

}
```

```html
<div id="box"> text here..</div>
```